# use SELECT to have two records (rows) in result 'table' in Mysql

Tags: mysql

In Mysql we can do

```
SELECT 'nathan' AS name
```

to have a result set with one record:

**name**
nathan

But how could I have the result table to have multiple records inside so that the result table would be like:

**name**
nathan
josh
hao

PS. The records does not exist in database and also won't exist in the database after running the query.

Thank you for helping

Comment: why, why, why would you need this?

Comment: All kinds of temporary purposes, I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT 'nathan' AS name union all
SELECT 'josh' AS name union all
SELECT 'hao' AS name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/16055)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I am a newbie to mysql and I always thought union is to have more columns instead of rows....

Comment: @riceTale UNION/UNION ALL is used to combine multiple queries.  In this case, your query is just selecting a static string.

Comment: @riceTale Just remember that you can have only one ORDER BY clause here, and it goes after the final statement in the UNION.